# How do you recharge an enchanted item?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I enchanted my Elvish bow to do frost damage.  However it only had 14 charges and has since run out.  Is there a way for me to recharge it? or is that bow kinda done for me now?

Comment: Good question, out of votes for the day though.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Click the item and press Charge - on PC it's default to `T`. You'll need a charged soul gem, though (the level of soul gem dictates the charge returned). This uses up the soul gem.

Comment: There's also a perk in the Enchanting tree that will restore some charge when you kill an enemy with an enchanted weapon.

Comment: Yeah, I got that perk, but when I enchanted the bow, I was unaware that there was a slider bar to decrease the damage to increase the charges.  Given that, 5% of a petty creature doesn't do anything for my bow =)

Comment: When you say "uses up", does that mean the gem loses the soul in it, or does the gem itself disappear?

Comment: @andronikus The gem is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks, I eventually figured that one out.  Makes me glad about this bug (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37080/soul-gems-losing-their-soul) so that I don't have to waste my Grand Soul Gem (Petty) 's.

Comment: How do you do this on the Xbox?

Comment: @andronikus to expand on Brian Ortiz comment, normal gems are destroyed when used however Azura's Star/The Black Star aren't destroyed and just use up the soul they have inside