# Soul Gems losing their soul

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I had Lesser Soul Gems stored in my cupboard they were definately filled before I took them out (they had (Lesser) beside them) but then when i took them out they were empty :( just wondering if this is a known glitch or just me.

I've done it with more than one Gem so it wasnt just a one off.

Comment: I haven't had personal experience of this in Skyrim nor do I know for definite if it's a "glitch" but I do know previous Elder Scrolls games suffered with all kinds of glitches if you left something in a location (Even a chest or cupboard) where items would disappear.

Comment: It was the cupboard in my house (Breezehome or something like that) so it's not being replaced.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't make myself clear enough. I didn't mean that the items are being replaced, simply that the previous games have been glitchy enough in this area in the past to make me think that this type of glitchy behaviour might occur. Actually there is a post on Reddit where someone is reporting a similar thing: http://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/mbxi5/basic_enchanting_and_soul_gem_guide_spoilers_are/c2zulft

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a fairly well-known glitch.  Although I haven't tried it myself, I've seen many people suggesting that you can empty soul gems by placing them in a container, then taking them back out.  (Useful if your grand gems are all filled with petty souls...)

Answer (score 2):

I know that when you drop a Soul gem, it loses its soul.  Sounds like a glitch, but maybe storing a soul gem does the same thing.