# How to recharge a Staff in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you recharge an enchanted item?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35475/how-do-you-recharge-an-enchanted-item)

I am at level 13 and have 3 staffs at the moment. I can capture souls and have trapped a few in soul gems.

How do I recharge a staff? Because at the arcane enchanter, staves are not shown in the list of items. Also I can enchant a weapon only if I've learnt an enchantment by destroying an enchanted weapon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To recharge a staff, go to your inventory, and select the staff. If you're on Xbox you can press RB to recharge it with soul gems filled with souls. If you're playing on PC/PS3, it'll say "press button to recharge" in the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Thanks, Actually I don't need to go to arcance enchanter to Recharge ANY item. Open the inventory, select item and Press 'T' (PC)

Answer (score 5):

You can recharge a staff in the same fashion as any enchanted item.  When you are viewing the staff in your inventory, there will be an option (the button depends on the platform) to recharge the staff using a filled soul gem.  The higher the soul the more charges will be restored.